# What is the difference between git pull and git pull origin <branchName>

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a parent branch `origin/develop` , from this branch I have created a child branch `feature/NewFeatureBranch`

I am now on `feature/NewFeatureBranch` using `git checkout feature/NewFeatureBranch`

Now I have done `git pull` and can see  several new branches downloading to my local machine which all have parent as `develop`

In another scenario I have done `git pull origin develop` and in this case newly checked in files from other branches towards `develop` are getting downloaded.

so is it that `git pull` is behaving like `git fetch` and `git pull origin develop` is behaving like `git fetch + git merge` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first words of the documentation:

> In its default mode, git pull is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by git merge `FETCH_HEAD`.

So `git pull` is just a shorthand. Git makes some assumptions about what you mean and supplies the missing pieces. And so, by default what it's a shorthand for is:

```
git fetch
git merge <remote-tracking-branch-that-current-branch-tracks> [into the current branch]
```

Similarly, if you actually give a remote and a branch, you are *still* saying:

```
git fetch remote
git merge remote/branch [into the current branch]
```

You can change the meaning of the shorthand (as part of your `config` setup), for example to `rebase` instead of `merge`, but most people don't. In general, some people regard it as better not to say `git pull` at all, but to say the `fetch` and then, if desired, the `merge` or the `rebase` or whatever, explicitly. This gives you a chance to "look around" and decide how to proceed.